# Values inserted with jquery aren't submitted in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a modal with a form:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="../system/file_change.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right replacefile" value="<?php echo $data['text_replace']?>">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $order_id; ?>">
            <input name="old_code" type="hidden" id="old_code">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And a script, which dinamycally insert a value to input name="old_code" field:

```
<script>
$('.replacefile').on('click', function(){
    $('#old_code').val($(this).attr('data-id'));
    console.log( $('#old_code').attr('value')); 
});
</script>
```

console log gives back the correct code.
My question is, why this code is not submitted with form? And how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Seems to work okay for me here, only thing I can think of is do you have another id 'old_code' on the page somewhere?

Comment: I think you should set attribute value="" for the old_code  input, because that's where you are inserting the value.

Comment: yes, i can access $_POST['order_id'], and $_POST['token'] too, but cant access: $_POST['old_code'], i have var dumb after wich says:string(40) "bb03c92dcfada919d5170661986d1d603653d030" string(0) "" string(2) "78"  where string (0)"" is the old_code

Comment: @Peszo what do you get when doing: print_r($_REQUEST); on the file_change page? (You should see old_code in the array even if it has no value)

Comment: try to use $('form').on('submit',function(){}) instead

Comment: Array ( [submit] => text_replace [order_id] => 78 [old_code] => [token] => 90946f746af0ffbca31033a8bb42e8d3 [PHPSESSID] => hea76ho43lokekvjva36rjadk4 [currency] => EUR )

Comment: .replacefile has no data-id attribute, do you mean to get the value?  - $(this).val()

Comment: Izion, thank you! di have deleted the class, now it is working. Was my mistake, because unfortunately i forget to delete this class after long experimenting.

Comment: Your welcome, have fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<script>
$('.replacefile').on('click', function(){
    $('#old_code').val($(this).val());
    console.log( $('#old_code').val()); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form role="form" id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" action="../system/file_change.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right replacefile" value="<?php echo $data['text_replace']?>">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $order_id; ?>">
        <input name="old_code" type="hidden" id="old_code">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
    $('.replacefile').on('click', function(){
    $('#old_code').val($(this).attr('data-id'));
    console.log( $('#old_code').attr('value')); 
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
</script>
```

Try above code